# Why does php redirect me instead of showing the alerts?

Tags: php

I have a registration form, after successful register, i want the user to be redirected to `home.php` (it works)
But also i want to show errors/alerts, which are im redirected to register.php (white page and it shows them there)

```
include 'main.php';

$errors = []; // collect errors in here


//echo the errors
// Now we check if the data was submitted, isset() function will check if the data exists.
if (!isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['cpassword'], $_POST['email'])) {
 // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
 exit('<div class="error form">Please complete the registration form!</div>');
}
// Make sure the submitted registration values are not empty.
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
 // One or more values are empty.
 exit('<div class="error form">Please complete the registration form!</div>');
}
// Check to see if the email is valid.
if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
 exit('<div class="error form">Email is not valid!</div>');
}
// Username must contain only characters and numbers.
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST['username'])) {
 exit('<div class="error form">Username is not valid!</div>');
}
// Password must be between 5 and 20 characters long.
if (strlen($_POST['password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 6) {
 exit('<div class="error form">Password must be between 6 and 20 characters long!</div>');
}
// Check if both the password and confirm password fields match
if ($_POST['cpassword'] != $_POST['password']) {
 exit('<div class="error form">Passwords do not match!</div>');
}




// Check if the account with that username already exists

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ? OR email = ?');
$stmt->execute([ $_POST['username'], $_POST['email'] ]);
$account = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
if ($account) {
 // Username already exists
 echo '<div class="error form">Username and/or email exists!</div>';
} else {
 // Username doesn't exist, insert new account
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email, activation_code) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
// We do not want to expose passwords in our database, so hash the password and use password_verify when a user logs in.
 $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 $uniqid = account_activation ? uniqid() : 'activated';
 $stmt->execute([ $_POST['username'], $password, $_POST['email'], $uniqid ]);


// Login in the user
 session_regenerate_id();
 $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
 $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
 $_SESSION['id'] = $pdo->lastInsertId();
 $_SESSION['role'] = 'the default role';
 if (account_activation) {
     // Account activation required, send the user the activation email with the "send_activation_email" function from the "main.php" file
     send_activation_email($_POST['email'], $uniqid);
     echo 'Please check your email to activate your account!';
 } else {
     // use content negotiation to determine response type
     if ($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] === "application/json") {
         if (count($errors)) {
             header("Content-type: application/problem+json");
             http_response_code(400);
             exit(json_encode([
                 "message" => "Invalid form data or something",
                 "errors" => $errors
             ]));
         }
         header("Content-type: application/json");
         exit(json_encode(["location" => "home.php"]));
     }


 }}

foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>
 <div class="error"><?= $error ?></div>
<?php endforeach;?>
?>
```

and this is my ajax call

```js
<script>
        document.querySelector(".register form").addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()

            const form = e.target

            const body = new FormData(form)

            // fetch is much easier to use than XHR
            const res = await fetch(form.action, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    accept: "application/json", // let PHP know what type of response we want
                },
                body
            })

            const data = await res.json()

            if (res.ok) {
                location.href = data.location
            } else if (res.status === 400) {
                document.querySelector('.msg').textContent = data.message
                // also do something with data.errors maybe
            }
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to decide whether your API returns HTML or JSON. You can't mix them like you are.

Comment: Please show the correct solution!

Comment: I'd have to redesign the whole thing.

Comment: This looks like another duplicate question. Did you post the same thing earlier and delete it? Or maybe use a different username?

Comment: @barmar I don't know how that helps my question, im looking for an answer

Comment: I suggest you send the errors as json

Comment: Put the error messages in the `$errors` variable instead of sending them as HTML.

Comment: @Barmar please show me an example

Comment: `if (!isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['cpassword'], $_POST['email'])) {
 $errors[] = 'Please complete the registration form!');
}`

Comment: @Barmar , I did that, it will redirect me to blank register.php page echoing ```Please complete the registration form!``` (but register works well)

Comment: @MariaRaynor Please let me know how i could approach that

Comment: You just asked for an example. You need to revise all the rest of the logic to work properly with this. So you shoiuld skip the code that performs the database query if there are any errors.

Comment: Like I said, you need to completely rewrite this.

Comment: @Barmar Sure, i just dont understand why the alerts are being redirected to register.php as well. My question still remains, im sorry for spam

Comment: I can't see any reason for that. Calling a script with `fetch()` shouldn't redirect to that page.

Comment: I don't see it either, i think i will re-open same question because the mystery is still unanswered